# accessing attached property from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<telerik:RadTransitionControl   x:Name="radControl" adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.ItemChangeDelay="0:0:3" 
                                      adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.CurrentSelectedIndex="0"
                                      adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.IndexChanged="{Binding TopItemCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                      adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ImagePaths}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="650">
```

please tell me how can i access the  adRotator:AdRotatorExtensions.ItemsSource from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`radControl.SetValue(AdRotatorExtensions.ItemsSource, ImagePaths);`

But I recommend to use a viewmodel and binding.

Comment: i am using the ViewModel, but i need to change the binding depending on the name given to the usercontrol

Comment: so you mean changing the binding from the view model, not from the code behind of the window?

Answer (score 0):

By convention, AdRotatorExtensions should expose a static method for retrieving the attached property value:

```
AdRotatorExtensions.GetItemsSource(radControl);
```

The above static method should perform the required cast. Otherwise, use `getValue`:

```
radControl.SetValue(AdRotatorExtensions.ItemsSource);
```

However, you have to cast the result to the required type.

See the [MSDN page on attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#custom) for details.